# vague HTTP errors uploading larger files from within wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I manage a small website for a private school, needing to post a variety of photos of videos.  Most files larger than a few mb attempt to upload, usually the progress bar finishing (for whatever that's worth) and then before it reloads the Media Library it just gives a vague HTTP error on the page.

I've researched this as much as possible and nothing I've tried seems to do anything.

**Current htaccess settings based on others' suggestions...**

```
SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1

<FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value post_max_size 128M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
</IfModule>
```

Tried disabling all plugins and no change I was able to notice.

**Server setup..**

GoDaddy Deluxe Shared
Wordpress 4.8 (latest)
PHP Version 5.6.30
CGI/FastCGI

I know it makes more sense to let Vimeo/YT/etc handle videos but they're worried about privacy since it's kids so preferred to keep everything on-site and as far as I can tell you can't embed videos with privacy options enabled, which makes sense.

GoDaddy's not much help.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or have a fix that works?  Happy to provide any other info needed.

Thanks!   Rich

Comment: Could you include the contents of the error? Also as an aside I think Vimeo Pro allows fine grained control  over what sites are allowed to embed your video.

Comment: It sounds like the max file upload size is lower than is currently needed. This could be set either at any number of places on the server. What size is the file you are trying to upload? If you go to the media section in WordPress admin, and then to the upload tab what does it say is the max allowed upload size?

Comment: Max upload size is 128mb...  ALL files attempted have been well below.